# How to search call trees in large codebases?

Tags: doxygen, callstack, ag

I'm trying to find if `functionX` is ever called by `functionY` by way of any other number of functions (let's call them `functionA`, `functionB`, and `functionC`) in a large codebase that fortunately does not make excessive use of callback functions.

I'm clicking through doxygen include-dependency-graphs manually (read inefficiently).  How can I search more effectively? Can `ag` save me?

Example call graph:

[image]

taken from: https://codeyarns.com/2013/12/24/how-to-create-header-include-graph-using-doxygen/

Comment: When trying to show an image, include the image as people don't like to click on unknown links and external references might get lost over time.

Comment: Did you have a look at the configuration options CALL_GRAPH and CALLER_GRAPH?

Comment: @albert, updated.

Comment: also `CALL_GRAPH`, `CALLER_GRAPH` and all dependent options are enabled and working.  this just takes way too long to manually sift through and those also have limited available as private functions are included

Comment: It is not easy to follow all those path especially when everything is deeply nested. I assume that you have set MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH to a reasonable level for your purpose so that you can see multiple levels of function calls (pointer to function and callback function make these tasks indeed harder to find).

Comment: `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES = 50` and `MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH = 0` (no restriction).  I think I'm looking for something more like gnu global.

Comment: if you mean that you don't want to look at visualizations of the call graph, but want to search it with ag/grep/etc. Have you considered egypt: http://www.gson.org/egypt/? This perl program will generate a text based call graph that you could then search with ag.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `DOT_CLEANUP = NO` in your configuration and run Doxygen again
2. Find the call graph dot file for `functionX` (will have a similar name as to the image generated, but with a `.dot` extension)
3. Search that dot file for `functionY`.

You can equally search for `functionX` in the caller graph `.dot` file of `functionY`.

BTW, you didn't post a call graph image; you posted an include tree.  I assume that was that a mistake, and that you do have `CALL_GRAPH=yes` (and/or `CALLER_GRAPH=yes`).